# How to copy multiple folders from a library to a single folder on the desktop?

Tags: ms-access, copy, paste, explorer

I'm very, very new to VBA. Your help is appreciated!!

I work for a custom millwork company and we need to coordinate work with other trades and their equipment. Because I provide our drafting team with specs for that equipment, I decided to develop a vendor "library" on our server, which is very simply Windows Explorer as C:\Library\Vendor\Model.

Within ACCESS, I can search the library for specific equipment models, and either follow a hyperlink to open the library location (the folder) for that item, or make multiple selections by use of a check box. A query of selected items can be output as PDF as a list containing live hyperlinks to again, open the library items one at a time.

What I would like to do instead is click a button and allow VBA to copy the folder for each library location  to a single folder location on the desktop. In this way, that single folder will contain all of the coordination information which needs to be provided to our drafting team.

Thanks again for the help!!

I have no idea where to start. I can copy one specific folder to another specific folder but my needs are more dynamic. I want to copy the folder for each selected item to a single folder location on the desktop, one after the other from one set of query results.

Ex: I look up each hardware spec that I need, and I check the selection box. My query results for the selected items looks like this:

| Vendor | Model | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vendor1 | 12-34-245 | C:\Library\Vendor1\12-34-245 |
| Vendor2 | 9857-12544 | C:\Library\Vendor2\9857-12544 |
| Vendor3 | RT43-32A | C:\Library\Vendor3\RT43-32A |

This query that compiles the output to PDF uses the field Location with Expression “C:\Library\” & [Vendor]&”\”&[Model] to create the hyperlink, which is, in fact, the file path. I’m thinking that this same file path can direct the VBA to the desired folders and they can be copied to a single folder on the desktop called “Drafting Package”.

Answer (score 0):

So turn your query into a recordset, then loop through the recordset with locations (here location is the "URL" field is a string) moving the folders.  to understand lastFolders purpose remove it.

```
Public Sub somebuttonclick()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Locations")
moveFolders rs, "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\B" 'example of URL as well
'clean up
rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub moveFolders(records As Recordset, urlDestination As String)
With records
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
.MoveLast  'skippable
.MoveFirst
While Not .EOF
copyFolder records("URL"), urlDestination
.MoveNext
Wend
End If
End With
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub copyFolder(urlStarting As String, urlDestination As String)
'requires reference to microsoft scripting runtime . from code editor Tools-References
Dim lastFolder As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
lastFolder = getLastFolder(urlStarting)

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
'note how the detination url needs the last folder
'fso.copyFolder "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\A\A", "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\B\A"
fso.copyFolder urlStarting, urlDestination & "\" & lastFolder
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Public Function getLastFolder(url As String)
   Dim stringArray() As String
   stringArray = Split(url, "\")
    getLastFolder = stringArray(UBound(stringArray))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'll have to keep working at it. I get a pop up window which seems to be looking for a macro. As a newbie, I cannot figure out what's amiss. I believe I've edited your programming to correctly identify the qry where the data exists and where the folders should be copied to. Still, I'm closer than I was before so thank you again.

Comment: Perhaps Access can't find some of the functions.  try putting all the functions in a code module where they can be accessed anywhere.  Also replace somebutton click with the click event for an actual button.  choose code when the button asks whether you want to embed code or a macro.